# css how to make <a> text align bottom?

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

How how to make `<a>` text align bottom? I have added `height` = `line-height`, and `vertical-align:bottom;` but the text still in the middle of the div. How to do? Thanks

Test in http://jsfiddle.net/BanAz/

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
#layer{width:198px;height:48px;line-height:48px;border:1px #000 solid;vertical-align:bottom;}
#layer a{text-decoration:none;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="layer">
<a href="#">menu</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Options include:

- Remove `line-height: 48px` and add `display: table-cell` to `#layer`:
  http://jsfiddle.net/jgQ9k/1/
  Note that this won't work for IE7, because `display: table-cell` isn't supported.
- Use a large `line-height`: http://jsfiddle.net/jgQ9k/2/

And the method I would actually use:

- Add `position: relative` to `#layer`, and `position:absolute; bottom:0` to `#layer a`:
  http://jsfiddle.net/jgQ9k/3/

Answer (score 1):

The **height** size (48px) is equal to **line-height** size (48px). Try to increase the height size, and you will see the css properties work fine and the text will be positioned on the bottom

Answer (score 0):

```
#layer {
    display: table-cell;
}
```